# floating columns underneath each other

Tags: css, html

I am having issues trying to get my **col3** and **col4** to float underneath each other.  The 100% width is based on **960px**.  I have tried floating but am getting no where.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9YRS/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listingAttributes">
<div class="col0">
<span class="name">Bedrooms:</span>
<span class="value">2</span>

<span class="name">Bathrooms:</span>
<span class="value">4</span><br/>

<span class="name">Price:</span></br>
<span class="value">Asking price $1,250,000</span></p>                                                          
</div>
<div class="col1">
<span class="name">Floor area:</span>
<span class="value">200m²</span>
<span class="name">Land area:</span>
<span class="value">1452m²</span>
<span class="name">Rateable value</span>
<span class="value">$980,000</span>                                                                     
</div>
<div class="col2">
<span class="name">Open home times:</span>
<span class="value">
<p>Sat 1 Dec 2 pm - 2:45pm</p>
<p>Sun 2 Dec 2 pm - 2:45pm</p>

</span>
</div>

<div class="col3">
<span class="name">In the area</span><br/>
<span class="value">Schools, Cafe's, Orewa Beach, Surfclub, Orewa Village, Silverdale Mall Wenderholm Park. Boat Ramp</span>
</div>
<div class="col4">
<span class="name">Parking</span><br/>
<span class="value">Double Garage w space for 4 more vehicles outside plus dedicated boat bay</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.listingAttributes{
    width:100%;
    height:165px;
    margin: 15px 10px -5px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFB400;
    background-color: red;
}
.listingAttributes .col0, .col1{
    width:160px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.listingAttributes .col2{
    width:180px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.listingAttributes .col3{
    width:350px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.listingAttributes .col4{
    width:350px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;   
}
.listingAttributes .sectionListingAttributes, .name{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: you can only float left or right. Do you mean you want col4 under col3 in the red div?

Comment: in your fiddle, col4 is underneath col3. I'm confused about what the problem is.

Comment: @Colleen Its not in the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to clear the float.

Simply add:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

after col3 DIV.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9YRS/6/)

col3 and col4 in the red area :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9YRS/16/)

Answer (score 0):

on col4 remove the property `float:left;` and make it `display:block;` not `display:inline-block;`

Also, remove the height on the parent `<div class="listingAttributes">` if you want col3 and col4 inside the red div.

Answer (score 0):

The `.listingAttributes .col3` and `.listingAttributes .col3` rules can be simplified to:

```
.listingAttributes .col3{
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9YRS/5/

---

I just read the part about everything being inside the red block. In that case, remove the `height` property from the `.listingAttributes` rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9YRS/7/